# Expire push notification after delivered to device

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to expire a push notification after delivered to a device. I know that you can expire a notification with the `time_to_live` or `expiration_interval` set inside the JSON, which is send to APN or GMS.

But is it possible to hide/clear a push notification after, say 10 min?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Felix, it is not possible to hide/clear a push notification after being sent. You just can replace a notification that is not yet delivered by setting it to a [Collapsible Message](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages):

> A collapsible message is a message that may be replaced by a new message containing the same collapse key if it has yet to be delivered to the device.

Here is a sample json format message:

```
{
"collapse_key" : "demo",
"delay_while_idle" : true,
"to" : "xyz",
"data" : {
"key1" : "value1",
"key2" : "value2",
},
"time_to_live" : 3
}
```

If another message will be queued with the same collapse key, the newer message will be sent and the older message will be disregarded. I hope it clear some question regarding setting up an expiration to the notification.